# Can anyone assist me with a group by with rollup and ranking query?

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

I need to display the three shortest books for each publisher. I can not report any books for which I have no page count; do not report any publisher for which we have no books. Some publishers may
have only 1 or 2 books. Display the first 25 characters of the book title. Finding the ties for third place is optional but more fun. The report is displayed in publisher id and rank order.

Here is the desired output:
[image]

```
set @rownum:= 0;
SELECT publ_id
     , title
     , page_count
     , @rownum:= @rownum + 1 as Rank
 FROM a_bkinfo.books 
 WHERE publ_id IN
       ( 
         SELECT publ_id
           FROM a_bkinfo.books
          GROUP BY publ_id
         HAVING SUM(page_count) =
                (
                  SELECT max(page_count)
                    FROM (  
                           SELECT publ_id
                                , sum(page_count) as page_count
                             FROM a_bkinfo.books 
                            GROUP BY publ_id
                         ) t
                )
       );
```

Here is the create table:

```
-- create books
create table a_bkinfo.books (
    book_id           integer          not null
  , title             varchar(75)      not null 
  , publ_id           integer          null
  , year_publd        integer          not null
  , isbn              varchar(17)      null
  , page_count        integer          null  
  , list_price        numeric(6,2)     null  
  , constraint bk_books_pk             primary key (book_id)
  , constraint bk_books_publ_fk        foreign key(publ_id) 
               references a_bkinfo.publishers  (publ_id)
  , constraint book_id_range           check (book_id > 1000)
  , constraint bk_page_count_ck        check (page_count >= 0)
  , constraint bk_price_ck             check (list_price >= 0)             
  , constraint bk_books_year_ck        check (year_publd >= 1850)
)engine = INNODB;
```

Here are the inserts:

```
-- books  
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1101, 'Programming SQL Server with VB.NET',              9000, 2002, '0735615357',    300, 59.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1102, 'Practical Standards for VB.NET',                  9000, 2003, '0735613568',    250, 49.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1103, 'Selected Poems',                                  9456, 1949,  null,           125, 12.00);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1104, 'Sibley Guide to Bird Life and Behavior',          9102, 2001, '0679451234',    604, 45.00);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1105, 'SQL:1999 Relational Language Concepts',           9745, 2002, '1558604561',    450, 59.95);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1106, 'SQL for Smarties',                                9745, 1995, '1558603239',    250, 29.00);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1107, 'SQL Puzzles and Answers',                         9745, 1997, '1558604537',    325, 25.00);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1108, 'Database Systems',                                9325, 1996,  null,           680, 39.95);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1109, 'Intro to DB Systems-7th Ed',                      9325, 2000, '0201385902',    650, 80.00);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1110, 'Adv SQL:1999 Object_Relational Features',         9745, 2002, '1558606077',    520, 59.95);


insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1128, 'Temporal Data and the Relational Model',          9325, 2003, 'na',            275, 49.95);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1133, 'Leaves of Grass',                                 9623, 1902,  null,           125, 19.95);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1142, 'Relational Database Theory',                      9521, 1993,  null,           879, 95.00);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1161, 'SQL Programming Style',                           9745, 2005, '0120887975',    780, 35.00);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1162, 'Trees and Hierarchies',                           9745, 2004, '1558609202',    350, 35.00);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1180, 'MySQL Database Design and Tuning',                9825, 2005, '9780672234650', 400, 49.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1175, 'MySQL in a Nutshell',                             9822, 2008, '9780596514331', 538, 34.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1182, 'MySQL Cookbook',                                  9822, 2007, '9780596527082', 918, 49.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1185, 'MySQL Stored Procedures',                         9822, 2007, '9780596100896', 595, 49.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1184, 'MySQL Developer''s Library',                      9325, 2009, '9780672329388', 650, 49.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1301, 'ADO and Oracle Workbook',                         9000, 2002, '0265615357',      0, 59.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1302, 'ADO: the ebook',                                  9000, 2002, '0852515358',   null, 49.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1303, 'Rainbows and Rainbows',                           9521, 2002, '0657895157',   null, 59.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1304, 'Stories of Discoveries',                          9325, 2002, '0777788887',    300, 59.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1305, 'Journeys Through Flatland',                       9325, 1958, '0387515357',    100,  9.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1306, 'Myths of SQL',                                    9664, 2000, '0454615027',   2895,259.99);



insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1188, 'SQL for MySQL Developers',                        9325, 2007, '9780314973851', 105, 49.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1199, 'SQL is Fun',                                      null, 2007,  null,            98, 19.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2001, 'Programming SQL Server 2005',                     9822, 2006, '0596003216',    675, 49.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2002, 'SQL Server 2005 A Beginner''s Guide',             9030, 2006, '0072260939',    402, 39.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2003, 'SQL Server 2005 Developer''s Guide',              9030, 2006, '0072260998',    402, 49.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2004, 'SQL Server 2005 Stored Procedure Prg',            9030, 2006, '0072262888',    399, 59.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2005, 'Developer''s Guide to SQL Server 2005',           9325, 2006, '0321382188',    894, 59.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2006, 'T_SQL Programming (Inside series)',               9000, 2006, '9780756978',    390, 44.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2007, 'T_SQL Querying (Inside series)',                  9000, 2006, '9780733132',    391, 44.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2008, 'SQL Server 2005 T_Sql Recipies',                  9444, 2006, '159059570X',    503, 59.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2009, 'SQL Server 2005 Express Edition',                 9664, 2006, '0764589237',    150, 29.99);



insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1258, '.Net Development for Microsoft Office',           9000, 2005, '0735621322',    500, 49.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1689, 'Programming Visual Basic 2005: The Language',     9000, 2006, '9780735621831', 980, 59.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1678, 'Pro .NET 2.0 Windows Forms and Controls VB 2005', 9444, 2006, '1590959693',   1002, 49.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1278, 'Beginning VB 2008 Databases',                     9444, 2008, '9781590599471', 408, 44.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1478, 'Beginning OO Programming with VB 2005',           9444, 2006, '1590597695',    368, 44.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1894, 'Programming Visual Basic 2005',                   9822, 2005, '0596009496',    548, 39.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1279, 'Data-Driven Services with Silverlight 2',         9822, 2009, '9780596523091', 336, 44.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1776, 'Doing Objects in Visual Basic 2005',              9325, 2007, '9780321320490', 500, 49.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1948, 'Framework Design Guidelines',                     9325, 2006, '0321246756',    346, 44.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1077, 'Programming for Poets',                           9456, 2009, null,            401, 40.25);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1835, 'Data Binding with Windows Forms 2.0',             9325, 2006, '032126892X',    634, 49.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1541,  'Freethinkers: A History of American Secularism', 9023, 2004, '9780805077766', 448, 12.79);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1542,  'The Great Agnostic: Robert Ingersoll and American Freethought',  
                                                                                            9021, 2013, '9780300137255', 256, 16.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1543,  'Ties That Bind:The Story of an Afro-Cherokee Family in Slavery and Freedom',  
                                                                                            9024, 2006, '9780520250024', 327, 26.96);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1544,  'The House on Diamond Hill: A Cherokee Plantation Story',  
                                                                                            9024, 2012, '9780807872673', 336, 17.76);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1545,  'Team of Rivals: The Political Genius of Abraham Lincoln',  
                                                                                            9776, 2006, '9780739469767', 944, 13.96);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1546,  'The Johnstown Flood',                            9776, 1987, '9780671207144', 304, 10.39);


insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1677, 'Windows Forms 2.0 Programming',                   9325, 2006, '0321267966',    982, 74.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1670, 'Applied .NET Framework Programming VB.NET',       9000, 2003, '0735678772',    608, 49.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1401, 'Visual Studio Tools for Office',                  9325, 2006, '0321334884',    976, 54.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1537, 'The BedSide Book of Birds',                       9725, 2005, '0385514832',     68, 29.95);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1357, 'Why Birds Sing',                                  9725, 2005, '046507135X',    240, 26.00);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1609, 'In the Company of Crows and Ravens',              9725, 2005, '0300100760',    376, 18.95);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1979, 'Pro VB 2008 and the .NET 3.5 Platform',           9444, 2008, '9781590598221',1368, 59.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1457, 'Visual Basic 2008 Recipes',                       9444, 2008, '9781590599709', 300, 79.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1425, 'The Singing Life of Birds',                       9561, 2005, '0618405682',    468, 28.09);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1978, 'Acoustic Communication in Birds Vol1',            9561, 1983, '9780124268012', 360,103.91);


insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1621,  'The Unfeathered Bird',                           9020, 2013, '9780691151342', 304, 31.29);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1622,  'Bird Sense',                                     9020, 2012, '9780802779663', 265, 25.00);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1623,  'Lichens of North America',                       9021, 2001, '9780300082494', 828,135.00);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1624,  'Outstanding Mosses and Liverworts of Pennsylvania and Nearby States',             
                                                                                            9021, 2006, '9780976092575',9, 19.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1626,  'Bark: A Field Guide to Trees of the Northeast',  9021, 2011, '9781584658528', 280, 25.95);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1625,  'Winter Weed Finder: A Guide to Dry Plants in Winter (Nature Study Guides)',              
                                                                                            9021, 1989, '9780912550176',  64,  4.95);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1627,  'The Ants',                                       9022, 1990, '9780674040755', 732,120.18);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1628,  'The Superorganism:The Beauty, Elegance, Strangeness of Insect Societies',               
                                                                                            9902, 2008, '9780393067040', 544, 34.65);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1629,  'The Leafcutter Ants: Civilization by Instinct',  9022, 1990, '9780393338683', 160, 19.95);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1630,  'The Social Conquest of Earth',                   9022, 2012, '9780871404138', 352, 27.95);



insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1448, 'Backyard Birdsong Guide: Western North America',  9561, 2008, '9780811863971',3192, 29.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1877, 'High Performance MySQL',                          9822, 2008, '9780596101718', 708, 49.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1200, 'The Mismeasure of Man',                           9902, 1996, '9780393314250', 488, 17.95);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1245, 'A Scientific Approach to SQL Testing',            9902, 2010, '9780366214250', 488, 52.95);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1774, 'Ever Since Darwin',                               9902, 1992, '9780393308181', 288, 15.95);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1234, 'Hen''s Teeth and Horse''s Toes ',                 9902, 1994, '9780393311037', 416, 17.95);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1269, 'Querying XML',                                    9745, 2006, '9781558607118', 848, 63.95);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1525, 'Interface-Oriented Design',                       9725, 2006, '0976697050',    213, 29.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1619, 'The Oject-Oriented Thought Process',              9725, 2004, '9780672326110', 158, 29.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (1483, 'Programming with XML',                            9745, 2008, null,            125, 19.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2017, 'Functional Programming',                          9528, 2010, '9781933988924', 528, 49.99);

insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2018,  'Oracle Database 11g SQL',                        9030, 2008, '9780071498500', 650, 49.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2025,  'Oracle SQL Fundamentals I Exam Guide',           9030, 2008, '9780071597869', 572, 59.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2027,  'Mastering Oracle SQL and SQL-Plus',              9444, 2005, '9781590594487', 464, 39.99);

insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2028,  'Mastering Oracle Databases',                     9444, 2010, '9781599594487', 464, 59.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2029,  'The Forgotten Bird Strikes Back ',               9030, 2010, '9091599594487',   5,  1.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2031,  'Comparative SQL',                                9444, 2013, '9781599591237', 750, 99.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2032,  'Oracle and the rest of the world',               9030, 2013, '9091599593217', 250, 55.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2622,  'Outstanding Bryophytes',                         9021, 2013, null,956, 89.99);
insert into a_bkinfo.books values (2623,  'Hornworts and Liverworts in your Garden ',       9021, 2013, null,501, 29.99);
```

I am totally lost. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP`

Answer (score 0):

To get three shortest books for each publisher **without ties**

```sql
SELECT publ_id, LEFT(title, 25) title, page_count,
(
  SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
    FROM books
   WHERE page_count IS NOT NULL
     AND page_count > 0
     AND publ_id    IS NOT NULL
     AND publ_id = t.publ_id
     AND (page_count < t.page_count 
          OR
         (page_count = t.page_count 
          AND
          book_id < t.book_id))  
) rank 
  FROM books t
 WHERE page_count IS NOT NULL
   AND page_count > 0
   AND publ_id    IS NOT NULL
HAVING rank <= 3
 ORDER BY publ_id, rank;
```

To get three shortest books for each publisher **with ties**

```sql
SELECT publ_id, LEFT(title, 25) title, page_count,
(
  SELECT 1 + COUNT(DISTINCT page_count)
    FROM books
   WHERE page_count IS NOT NULL
     AND page_count > 0
     AND publ_id    IS NOT NULL
     AND publ_id    = t.publ_id
     AND page_count < t.page_count
) rank 
  FROM books t
 WHERE page_count IS NOT NULL
   AND page_count > 0
   AND publ_id    IS NOT NULL
HAVING rank <= 3
 ORDER BY publ_id, rank;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a597e/1)** demo